# Update gradle plugin 3 with android SDK 28 proguard fail

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-3.0

After updating from version 2 to 3 of the plugin gradle, proguard shows now many warning. One of them is:

```
library class dalvik.system.DelegateLastClassLoader extends or implements program class dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
```

If I change the android sdk to 26 this warning dissapeard. Is this a bug of gradle or android?

I have seen many requests about gradle warnings after update to version 3, why is this happen on gradle plugin v3?

Comment: most likely it reads `Note: there were <insert random number> duplicate class definitions` somewhere above, which is a relevant detail, which is completely missing here. a single line excerpted from the build-log does not count as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). while [here](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#duplicateclass) is being explained, what to do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using the rule:

> -dontwarn dalvik.**

Not the best solution, but now I can build my app and everything seems fine.